# Controller Action isn't storing value in @ like it's supposed to

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following relationship:

```
hero.rb -> has_many :builds
build.rb -> belongs_to :hero
```

routes.rb

```
resources :heros, :path => '/heroes' do
  resources :builds
end
```

In the `index` action the following code works perfectly to find out what hero is in the url (**http://localhost:3000/heroes/tiny/builds**) which displays all of the builds of that specific hero.

```
@hero = Hero.find(params[:hero_id])
```

Why doesn't the same code work in the `show` action which has the url **http://localhost:3000/heroes/tiny/builds/the-best-build-ever** ? 
Neither of the following code seem to store the variables like they're supposed to:

```
@hero = Hero.find(params[:hero_id]) 
@build = Build.find(params[:id])
```

Here are the params from the development log file:  https://gist.github.com/1518721

Github Repo: https://github.com/imjp/DotA-Items

I've been struggling with this for a couple of hours and I just can't seem to figure it out :/

Comment: Because there's no id? Without detailing how you're mapping the request it's impossible to know for sure.

Comment: I've added the Routes.rb to the post. I'm using `friendly_id` to create the seo friendly urls for the show actions but that doesn't affect the `id` itself. Because the *.find(params[:id]) works just fine on the hero show action to find the current hero being showed.

Comment: is your `Hero` model extended using `FriendlyId` >

Comment: yup, otherwise the urls wouldn't be working ^_-

Comment: What does `params` look like when making that request in your example?

Comment: How do I find out what `params` looks like (noob question)? `<% if @build.present? %>` and `<% if @hero.present? %>` keep returning `false`, meaning that the value in the variables is `nil` :(

Comment: The value of params is output in your log file (log/development.log when in development)

Comment: Here's the output when I try to access the builds#show action: http://pastebin.com/T33anPKW

Comment: Nobody is able to help resolve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The controller's show action isn't storing the variables for some odd reason](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627794/the-controllers-show-action-isnt-storing-the-variables-for-some-odd-reason)

Comment: This is the params bit: Parameters: {"hero_id"=>"earthshaker", "id"=>"the-titan-build-for-earth-shaker-bro-pure-pain-and-shit-for-the-win-hehe"}

If you open your rails console, what do you get when you do Hero.find("earthshaker")

Comment: Thanks for helping out Joel, I've pasted the result on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/w1vGwAD4

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the code within the context of the controller itself. Also, please don't use Pastebin as its formatting is absolutely terrible. Instead, use http://gist.github.com instead.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ryan. I've updated the post and added my github project so you can browse the files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looked at your github repo, and you have defined the show method twice in your builds controller. That means none of the variables will be loaded, since the second instance of the method is just blank.

Comment: Joel: good find! And please, @imjp, clean up your code, that should not too hard, none of the indentations are correct, it is truly a pain to look at. No wonder you overlook the duplicate `show` method.

Comment: @Nathan: Could you post a gist of what a refactored version of builds_controller? Here I was thinking the code is pretty clean >.>

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out for me Joel. Had my entire app on hold for 2 days because of this t.t

Comment: Here's a re-whitespaced version of heros/builds controllers. I also slightly changed the lookup of builds in the heros controller.
https://gist.github.com/44806a7998cac4ad2cea